# How do I print an Instant as rfc2822 in NodaTime?

Tags: nodatime

I'm looking to print an Instant as rfc2822 in NodaTime. How?

Quick search leads to broken google-code links. I'd prefer a built-in named pattern over supplying all formatting to ToString.

Comment: Which were the broken links, btw? For text handling, read http://nodatime.org/userguide/text.html

Comment: The broken links all over google is on the mailing list, which link to google code. Hard to do anything about though :)

Comment: Yup. Although the user guide itself has been on nodatime.org for a couple of years now. All the code is now in github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd prefer a built-in named pattern over supplying all formatting to ToString.

If you mean you're expecting a "standard" pattern so to speak, there isn't one.

However, it's easy enough to write a custom pattern for this - giving you an `InstantPattern` instead of passing it all in `ToString`, as you mentioned.

Fortunately, *formatting* RFC 2822 is considerably simpler than *parsing* it - especially if you're happy to express everything in UTC. Looking at [RFC 2822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) itself, two things spring out:

- "The date and time-of-day SHOULD express local time." If you want to go along with that, you should be formatting an `OffsetDateTime` instead of an `Instant`.
- The day-of-week is optional - but in my experience it's pretty much expected to be there.

Ignoring the "should express local time" part, I'd use:

```
var pattern = InstantPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture
   ("ddd d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss '+0000'");
// Test it...
Console.WriteLine(pattern.Format(SystemClock.Instance.Now));
```

(Note for future readers: as of Noda Time 2.0, use `IClock.GetCurrentInstant()` instead of `IClock.Now`.)

Sample output:

```
Sat 4 Apr 2015 09:55:49 +0000
```

If you want to go down the `OffsetDateTimePattern` route, you want:

```
var pattern = OffsetDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture
    ("ddd d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss o<+HHmm>");
```

Then you'll get output such as:

```
Sat 4 Apr 2015 10:57:27 +0100
```

Comment: @Henrik: Very glad to hear Noda Time plays nicely with F#. Do let me know if there are any impedance mismatches that could be smoothed over :)

Comment: I've used NodaTime with F# for a long time now and it's really not anything that bothers me with it. If you want more polish for F# you could implement active patterns for the edge-cases (MinInstant, MaxInstant, etc) and a sprintf/kprintf compiler-assisted formatter for dates -- both of those would enhance type safety. Otherwise your lib is geared towards the same general idea that F# is; safe API usage through expressive types, which is why it fits so well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Would love to get more detail on both of the suggestions you've raised here - could you open enhancement requests on Github (https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/issues) with a bit more information or links? Let's see what we can do for 2.0 :)